# Set a public node to auto forge / mine / stake in NXT / Ardor without login via the gui?

Tags: nxt, forging, ardor, staking

Installed nxt/ardor on my public server and would like to have it auto mine / stake with an account. How can this be done without having to login to the gui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your linux box you can type the following:

```
curl -d requestType=startForging -d secretPhrase="PASSPHRASE" http://localhost:7876/nxt
```

--

```
Without curl: wget -qO- 'http://localhost:7876/nxt?requestType=startForging&secretPhrase=sssecrrretPhPhPhphrrrassssse'
```

https://nxtwiki.org/wiki/The_Nxt_API#Start_.2F_Stop_.2F_Get_Forging

You can use startForging, stopForging or getForging in order to start forging with an account, stop forging, or check that an account is forging.

Comment: ```Blacklisting 191.0.159.98 because of: Unexpected character (r) at position 0.```